# xterm fonts and font size

Tags: cygwin, xterm, xming

I am using Cygwin on Windows 7 with Xming (Xming 6.9.0.31). I have also installed the Xming fonts (Xming-fonts 7.5.0.34).

I tried more or less all possible combinations from the "VT Fonts" menu in xterm ("TrueType Fonts" on/off, from "Tiny" to "Huge"). However, I do not like any of the results: either the fonts are unproportinal, too bold or too thin, too large or to small, in one word fugly.

How can I select different fonts than the ones which are default to the "VT Fonts" menu?

Also, is there any way to adjust the font size in a stepless manner? (the default steps from Tiny to Huge are too coarse grained)

Answer (score 2):

The `-font` argument can take any valid X font specification. You can use `xfontsel` to select a X font specification of your choice.